# Add local image in React Project without webpack

Tags: reactjs, image

I am new to react wanted to know the steps to use the image tag in react .jsx file. I'm not using webpack yet.

below is the code in **app.jsx** file which is converted into **app.js** using babel

```
const fullName = "Test Name";
 
 
 
 const element = (
     <div title="Outer div">
         <h1 className='headerName'>{fullName}</h1>
         <img src={'/public/my_image.jpeg'} alt="my image" />
     </div>

 )

 ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById('myName'));
```

I'm getting 404 error in the console. please

Comment: Need to add a local image. Is it a correct way to use the src attribute in the image tag?

Comment: We have to keep the image in the src folder where the app.jsx is present. The image loads without any issues